# Problems in loading ts file, it throws error 'Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'angular2/angular2''

Tags: typescript, webpack, angular

> I'm using angular2.0.0-beta.0
>
> While loading ts file following error are thrown

```
[200] ./src/app/LoggedInOutlet.ts 2.76 kB {2} [built] [2 errors]
  [201] ./src/app/app.ts 1.83 kB {2} [built] [3 errors]
  [202] ./src/home/home.ts 2.93 kB {2} [built] [3 errors]
  [203] ./src/home/homeSecrets/GetSecrets.ts 2.81 kB {2} [built] [2 errors]
  [204] ./src/home/homeSecrets/secrets.ts 1.75 kB {2} [built] [2 errors]
  [205] ./src/home/moreTest.ts 1.31 kB {2} [built] [2 errors]
  [206] ./src/home/test1/test.ts 1.24 kB {2} [built] [2 errors]
  [207] ./src/home/test2/anotherTest.ts 1.3 kB {2} [built] [2 errors]
  [208] ./src/home/test3/LastTest.ts 1.33 kB {2} [built] [2 errors]
  [209] ./src/index.ts 395 bytes {2} [built] [2 errors]
  [210] ./src/login/login.ts 2.57 kB {2} [built] [2 errors]
  [211] ./src/signup/signup.ts 2.53 kB {2} [built] [2 errors]

ERROR in ./src/home/homeSecrets/GetSecrets.ts
(4,48): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'angular2/angular2'.

ERROR in ./src/home/homeSecrets/secrets.ts
(1,48): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'angular2/angular2'.

ERROR in ./src/home/moreTest.ts
(7,48): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'angular2/angular2'.

ERROR in ./src/home/test3/LastTest.ts
(4,48): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'angular2/angular2'.

ERROR in ./src/home/test2/anotherTest.ts
(7,48): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'angular2/angular2'.

ERROR in ./src/home/test1/test.ts
(7,48): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'angular2/angular2'.

ERROR in Z:\a2\typings\_custom\webpack.d.ts
(1,13): error TS2403: Subsequent variable declarations must have the same type.  Variable 'require' must be of type 'NodeRequire', but here has type 'any'.

ERROR in Z:\a2\typings\_custom\webpack.d.ts
(4,13): error TS2403: Subsequent variable declarations must have the same type.  Variable 'global' must be of type 'Global', but here has type 'any'.

ERROR in ./src/signup/signup.ts
(1,48): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'angular2/angular2'.

ERROR in ./src/login/login.ts
(1,31): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'angular2/angular2'.

ERROR in ./src/home/home.ts
(1,48): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'angular2/angular2'.

ERROR in ./src/home/home.ts
(24,14): error TS2345: Argument of type '({ path: string; redirectTo: string; } | { path: string; as: string; component: typeof Test; })[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'RouteDefinition[]'.
  Type '{ path: string; redirectTo: string; } | { path: string; as: string; component: typeof Test; }' is not assignable to type 'RouteDefinition'.
    Type '{ path: string; redirectTo: string; }' is not assignable to type 'RouteDefinition'.
      Types of property 'redirectTo' are incompatible.
        Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'any[]'.

ERROR in ./src/app/LoggedInOutlet.ts
(1,72): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'angular2/angular2'.

ERROR in ./src/app/app.ts
(1,31): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'angular2/angular2'.

ERROR in ./src/app/app.ts
(19,14): error TS2345: Argument of type '({ path: string; redirectTo: string; } | { path: string; as: string; component: typeof Home; } | ...' is not assignable to parameter of type 'RouteDefinition[]'.
  Type '{ path: string; redirectTo: string; } | { path: string; as: string; component: typeof Home; } | {...' is not assignable to type 'RouteDefinition'.
    Type '{ path: string; redirectTo: string; }' is not assignable to type 'RouteDefinition'.
      Types of property 'redirectTo' are incompatible.
        Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'any[]'.

ERROR in ./src/index.ts
(1,52): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'angular2/angular2'.

ERROR in multi angular2
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'angular2/angular2' in Z:\a2
 @ multi angular2

ERROR in ./src/index.ts
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'angular2/angular2' in Z:\a2\src
 @ ./src/index.ts 1:17-45

ERROR in ./src/app/app.ts
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'angular2/angular2' in Z:\a2\src\app
 @ ./src/app/app.ts 10:17-45

ERROR in ./src/app/LoggedInOutlet.ts
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'angular2/angular2' in Z:\a2\src\app
 @ ./src/app/LoggedInOutlet.ts 18:17-45

ERROR in ./src/login/login.ts
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'angular2/angular2' in Z:\a2\src\login
 @ ./src/login/login.ts 10:17-45

ERROR in ./src/home/home.ts
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'angular2/angular2' in Z:\a2\src\home
 @ ./src/home/home.ts 10:17-45

ERROR in ./src/signup/signup.ts
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'angular2/angular2' in Z:\a2\src\signup
 @ ./src/signup/signup.ts 10:17-45

ERROR in ./src/home/moreTest.ts
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'angular2/angular2' in Z:\a2\src\home
 @ ./src/home/moreTest.ts 13:17-45

ERROR in ./src/home/test1/test.ts
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'angular2/angular2' in Z:\a2\src\home\test1
 @ ./src/home/test1/test.ts 13:17-45

ERROR in ./src/home/test2/anotherTest.ts
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'angular2/angular2' in Z:\a2\src\home\test2
 @ ./src/home/test2/anotherTest.ts 13:17-45

ERROR in ./src/home/test3/LastTest.ts
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'angular2/angular2' in Z:\a2\src\home\test3
 @ ./src/home/test3/LastTest.ts 13:17-45

ERROR in ./src/home/homeSecrets/secrets.ts
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'angular2/angular2' in Z:\a2\src\home\homeSecrets
 @ ./src/home/homeSecrets/secrets.ts 15:17-45

ERROR in ./src/home/homeSecrets/GetSecrets.ts
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'angular2/angular2' in Z:\a2\src\home\homeSecrets
 @ ./src/home/homeSecrets/GetSecrets.ts 13:17-45
webpack: bundle is now VALID.
```

> My folder structure and tsconfig.json is as fallows
>   [image]

My webpack.config.js is as fallows

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
var path = require('path');
var sliceArgs = Function.prototype.call.bind(Array.prototype.slice);

module.exports = {
  devtool: 'source-map',
  // devtool: 'eval',

  //
  entry: {
    angular2: [
      // Angular 2 Deps
      'zone.js',
      'reflect-metadata',

      //'./src/common/BrowserDomAdapter',

      'angular2/angular2',
      'angular2/router',
      'angular2/core'
    ],
    app: [
      // App
      /*
      // * include any 3rd party js lib here
      */
      './src/index'
    ]
  },

  // Config for our build files
  output: {
    path: root('build'),
    filename: '[name].js',
    // filename: '[name].[hash].js',
    sourceMapFilename: '[name].js.map',
    chunkFilename: '[id].chunk.js'
    // publicPath: 'http://mycdn.com/'
  },

  resolve: {
    root: __dirname,
    extensions: [
      '',
      '.ts',
      '.js',
      '.json',
      '.webpack.js',
      '.web.js'
    ],
    alias: {
      // When Angular2 has a TypeScript build
      // we can switch between development and production
      // 'angular2': 'angular2/es6/prod',
      // 'angular2': 'angular2/es6/dev',
      //'webapp': 'src'
    }
  },

  module: {
    loaders: [
      // Support for *.json files.
      { test: /\.json$/,  loader: 'json' },

      // Support for CSS as raw text
      { test: /\.css$/,   loader: 'raw' },

      // support for .html as raw text
      { test: /\.html$/,  loader: 'raw' },

      // Support for .ts files.
      { test: /\.ts$/,    loader: 'ts' }
    ],
    noParse: [
      /rtts_assert\/src\/rtts_assert/
    ]
  },

  plugins: [
    new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
      name: 'angular2',
      minChunks: Infinity
    }),
    new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
      name: 'common',
      filename: 'common.js'
    }),
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'ENV': {
        'type': JSON.stringify('development'),
        'debug': true
      }
    }),

    // new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    new webpack.optimize.OccurenceOrderPlugin(),
    new webpack.optimize.DedupePlugin(),
    new webpack.BannerPlugin(getBanner())
  ],
  // our Development Server configs
  devServer: {
    inline: true,
    colors: true,
    historyApiFallback: true,
    contentBase: '.',
    publicPath: '/build'
  },
  debug: true,
  cache: true,

  context: __dirname,
  stats: { colors: true, reasons: true }
};

function getBanner() {
  return 'A demo project angular2 beta that had covered all functionality(e.g. routing, nested routing, directives, pipe, dependency injection etc) in easy understanding way';
}

function root(args) {
  args = sliceArgs(arguments, 0);
  return path.join.apply(path, [__dirname].concat(args));
}
function rootNode(args) {
  args = sliceArgs(arguments, 0);
  return root.apply(path, ['node_modules'].concat(args));
}
```

> **Note: As soon as I change angular version to "2.0.0-alpha.44" it works fine without any error

Comment: `Cannot find module 'angular2/angular2'.`, you should be importing from `angular2/core` by now, and you should also add `moduleResolution: node` in your tsconfig.json.

Comment: ok let me try. Thanks in advance

Comment: Hey friend, can you give me a link where I can find out a guide about "moduleResolution" or can you guide me what is it and how to add this to my tsconfig.json

Comment: This is the only thing I found about : [External resolution module logic](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/2338). Besides that I just saw that you seem to be using TS 1.5.0, you should be using 1.7.x. Just add the option I said in your `compilerOptions`.